# Über die Wendung(?) "in gut / in schlecht"

Tags: idiom

> Denn auch die konsumierten Inhalte haben in ihrer vermeintlichen Belanglosigkeit noch immer eine Funktion: Sie können dazu animieren, das, was man gerade gesehen hat, nachzumachen oder weiterzuentwickeln. **Das gibt es in gut** (Make-up-Tutorials oder Einrichtungsinspirationen) oder **in schlecht** (gesundheitsgefährdende YouTube-Challenges).

Dies sollte vielleicht soviel wie "Das kann man auf gute wie auf schlechte Weise benutzen" heißen.

Wieso findet man jedoch im Internet keine anderen Sätze mit dieser Wendung, falls man das überhaupt Wendung nennen kann? Oder hat sich der Autor des Textes die Fügung selbst ausgedacht?

Answer (score 4):

> Dies sollte vielleicht soviel wie "Das kann man auf gute wie auf schlechte Weise benutzen" heißen.

Sehr wahrscheinlich in dem Kontext, ja.

> Wieso findet man jedoch im Internet keine anderen Sätze mit dieser Wendung, falls man das überhaupt Wendung nennen kann?

Es ist mehr oder weniger eine umgangssprachliche Extrapolation von

> > das gibt es in **rot** ... oder **grün** ...

die nicht so oft benutzt wird.

> Oder hat sich der Autor des Textes die Fügung selbst ausgedacht?

Ich höre, lese das nicht zum ersten mal.

Comment: In Rot oder Grün wäre auch meine erste Analogie gewesen.

Answer (score 2):

Der Interpretation des Satzes mit

> "Das kann man auf gute wie auf schlechte Weise benutzen"

stimme ich nicht zu.

Aussagegleich wäre eher folgende Neuformulierung

> Dafür gibt es gute (Make-up-Tutorials oder Einrichtungsinspirationen)
>   und schlechte (gesundheitsgefährdende YouTube-Challenges) Beispiele.

---

Die Ausdrücke **in gut**, bzw. **in schlecht** sind keine neue Sprachschöpfung sondern schon seit längerer Zeit in Gebrauch. Allerdings ist **in gut** meiner Erfahrung nach deutlich gebräuchlicher. Meist in Zusammenhängen wie

> Mach das noch einmal und dieses Mal in gut.

oder

> Gibt es das auch in gut?

Mit dem ersten Satz soll ausgedrückt werden, dass der erste Versuch daneben ging/die Anforderungen nicht erfüllte und man sich mehr anstrengen soll.

Der zweite zeigt die Geringschätzung über etwas was einem gezeigt wird und die Aufforderung einem etwas besseres zu zeigen.

---

Beispiele für "Das gibt es in gut" habe ich übrigens auch auf die schnelle nicht gefunden. Dafür aber für "[nochmal in gut](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22nochmal%20in%20gut%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE792DE792&oq=%22nochmal%20in%20gut%22)", was zumindest die Verwendung der Wendung "in gut" zeigt.